# How to concatenate HOG and LBP feature descriptors?

Tags: python, opencv, scikit-learn, scikit-image

I am trying to use HOG and LBP feature descriptor to detect pedestrian.
But they have different size. HOG has basically 3780x1 feature vectors and LBP has 256x1 feature vectors.

can I just merge them put them into new array? but in this case, I doubt whether it will be properly trained.

how to concatenate two descriptors to be used in SVM classifier?

or how to train svm with multiple feature descriptors?

Comment: the order of the dimensions should not make a difference. But the fact that LBP is a binary descriptor smd HoG isnt could introduve problems I think, without really knowing.

Comment: Well, you certainly can try but as you said the results might not be what you want. It depends on the distribution of values etc. Also, normalization before concatenation might be a good choice

Comment: Some of the values of your attributes could be very small or very large. This difference between attributes can induce bias in the classifier. One way to un-bias your features is normalization, which scales your variables to between 0.0 and 1.0. You can also try standardization, which shifts values to have a mean of 0.0 and a standard deviation of 1.0. Every machine learning problem is different, so you will likely need to test and see what technique better fits your data.

Comment: @eldesgraciado
I already normalized two things.
and then just merge and train them with SVM?